# User Level MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

i used this code to protect my log in, but i had a problem with the password, for example i've two username  and two password...when i used Username both of password can log in...can anyone help...here the code i used...

```
 Private Sub cmdmsk_Click()
    Dim UserLevel As Integer
    Me.cmdmsk.SetFocus

    If IsNull(Me.txtuser) Then
        MsgBox "plis enter username", vbInformation, "Username needs to Login"
        Me.txtuser.SetFocus
    ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtpass) Then
        MsgBox "plis enter you password", vbInformation, "Password needs to login"
        Me.txtpass.SetFocus
    Else
        'process the job
        If (IsNull(DLookup("UserLogin", "tblUser", "UserLogin ='" & Me.txtuser.Value & "'"))) Or _ 
      (IsNull(DLookup("Password", "tblUser", "Password ='" & Me.txtpass.Value & "'"))) Then
            MsgBox "wrong pass or username"
        Else


           UserLevel = DLookup("UserSecurity", "tblUser", "UserLogin = '" & Me.txtuser.Value & "'")



                     If UserLevel = "1" Then

                      MsgBox "Cangratulations ^_^"
                      DoCmd.Close
                      DoCmd.OpenForm "MENU"

                      Else


                      DoCmd.Close
                      DoCmd.OpenForm "INPUT"
            End If
            End If
            End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do one look up only:

```
Private Sub cmdmsk_Click()

    Dim UserLevel As Variant

    Me!cmdmsk.SetFocus

    If IsNull(Me!txtuser.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter your username.", vbInformation, "Missing Username"
        Me!txtuser.SetFocus
    ElseIf IsNull(Me!txtpass.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter your password", vbInformation, "Missing Password"
        Me!txtpass.SetFocus
    Else
        'process the job
        UserLevel = DLookup("UserSecurity", "tblUser", _
            "[UserLogin] = '" & Me!txtuser.Value & "' And [Password] = '" & Me!txtpass.Value & "'")

        If IsNull(UserLevel) Then
            MsgBox "Incorrect username or password.", vbInformation, "Login"
        Else
            If UserLevel = "1" Then
                DoCmd.OpenForm "MENU"
            Else
                DoCmd.OpenForm "INPUT"
            End If
            DoCmd.Close
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```